# How to copy all file attributes to another file without modifying a content?

Tags: files, rsync, macos, chmod

I have file created and modified a few years ago. I would like to create new file B with different content, but same everything else, permissions, owner, group,  creation date, modified date. So that it would look like that file B was created a few years ago as well.

I was trying to use `rsync` but without luck. It always copy the content of of the file as well.

The closes call was on `cp --attributes-only --preserve a.txt b.txt` but on macbook it failed with
`cp: illegal option -- -`

Comment: I don't have access to OS X documentation, but `--attributes-only` sounds like a GNU coreutils `cp`-specific option. If this is really on Mac OS, please add a tag to your question that tells us about it! This might very well be operating system and userland-specific

Comment: thanks, added "macos" tag

Comment: Can you open [x-man-page://cp](x-man-page://cp) and check whether your cp supports the options starting with `--`?

Comment: I've check `man cp` and there's no info about --. Not even cp version, just says it's from 2005. So I guess the suggestion is to google how to do update cp on macbook?

Comment: no. this is just not a GNU cp, but a BSP cp. Different programs, *nearly* same functionality.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer. As [Marcus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/106650/marcus-m%C3%BCller) suggested in comments,
cp on macOS isn't the same as GNU cp.

So the command `cp --attributes-only --preserve a.txt b.txt` indeed works and copies only attributes without file content, but to run on a mac I needed to install GNU cp at first

`brew install coreutils`

and after the installation is done, run:

`gcp --attributes-only --preserve a.txt b.txt`

Comment: nice, good answer :) Please keep up the good work!